# Next pts does not match previous pts plus duration when transcoding an AAC audio with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming, http-live-streaming

In my understanding, the following statement must hold:

```
next pts = previous pts + duration
```

But, I got this list of `PTS`es from `ffprobe` that looks odd to me:

```
<packet codec_type="audio" ... pts="63000" duration="2089" duration_time="0.023211" ...>
<packet codec_type="audio" ... pts="65070" duration="2089" duration_time="0.023211" ...>
<packet codec_type="audio" ... pts="67140" duration="2089" duration_time="0.023211" ...>
<packet codec_type="audio" ... pts="69300" duration="2089" duration_time="0.023211" ...>
<packet codec_type="audio" ... pts="71370" duration="2089" duration_time="0.023211" ...>
<packet codec_type="audio" ... pts="73440" duration="2089" duration_time="0.023211" ...>
<packet codec_type="audio" ... pts="75510" duration="2089" duration_time="0.023211" ...>
<packet codec_type="audio" ... pts="77670" duration="2089" duration_time="0.023211" ...>
```

The corresponding `PTS` gaps are as follows. You can see none of the below gaps matches `2089`:

```
63000 <> 65070: 2070
65070 <> 67140: 2070
67140 <> 69300: 2160
69300 <> 71370: 2070
71370 <> 73440: 2070
73440 <> 75510: 2070
75510 <> 77670: 2160
```

I have no deep understanding of `AAC` or transcoding, so I talked with some random guy on `#ffmpeg`. As per what he said, the gap should be a fixed value:

```
20:01 -!- Icedream [~icedream@hzn-b.serverkomplex.de] has quit [Quit: A lol made me boom.]
20:02 < DeHackEd> I would expect them to increment at a constant rate, since AAC (which is probably what you're using) uses fixed size
                  audio chunks. But that's very inconsistent
20:03 < DeHackEd> (+/- 1 pts number would be acceptable)
```

To tell you the truth, this is a problematic video, **but not in a way you would expect**. I'm getting intermittent audio clipping sound, if two or more audio packets are crammed into a single `PES` packet. What's special about this configuration is that, the player must guess `PTS`es for the trailing audio packets except the first one. Since the `PTS` gaps are not consistent, the player must have used wrong `PTS`es for the trailing ones, and this looks to me like the cause.

But, what could be the trigger? Here are some contexts you can kindly refer to:

- the original video has no surprising `PTS` gap. This is the result from my custom-made script to extract all unique gaps:

```
$ ./foo.sh ./original.flv
diff 296448 occurs at 296448 // just a first packet (=has no previous packet)
diff 24 occurs at 296472
diff 23 occurs at 296495
```

- this is the command I used for transcoding:

```
$FFMPEG -hide_banner -loglevel info -nostats \
    -i $input \
    -map "[out1]" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t, n_forced*$keyFrameInterval)" -preset veryfast -vprofile high -minrate 4.5M -maxrate 6M -bufsize 6M \
    -map 0:a -c:a aac -b:a:1 128K -af "aformat=sample_rates=44100|48000:channel_layouts=stereo" \
    -map 0:a -c:a aac -b:a:2 32K -af "aformat=sample_rates=44100|48000:channel_layouts=stereo" \
    -f mpegts -tune zerolatency pipe:1 > \
        >($FFMPEG -hide_banner -loglevel info -nostats \
            -i - \
            -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:1 -c:a copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -tune zerolatency -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 ${output}_1080 \
            -map 0:v -s $(width 1280 720 $orientation)x$(height 1280 720 $orientation) -c:v libx264 -r 30 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t, n_forced*$keyFrameInterval)" -preset veryfast -vprofile high -minrate 3M -maxrate 4M -bufsize 4M -map 0:1 -c:a copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -f flv -tune zerolatency -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 ${output}_720 \
            ...
```